# How do you change an internal element in a wpf custom control thru a dependency property?

Tags: wpf

Assume you have a custom control with two shapes, and you want to change the color of one shape based on the sign of a dependency property, which would be numeric.

I guess the solution with XAML is to write a converter function and bind the shape to that code.

Here is the catch - I would like to do it via code, and not thru XAML binding.

Dependency properties are static and I'm having a hard time accessing any of the private elements that make up the control.

Could I just create a standard .net get/set property instead of the dependency property and do it that way? I tried doing that with a boolean value, and the properties pane at design time will not allow me to uncheck the boolean value, so I figure this is not a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to add PropertyChangedCallback, look at the lambda expression, were you call 
your private method through the instance that you're providing:

Code Behind your Control (lets call it myControl)

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IntegerValueProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("MYCustomDpProp", typeof(int?), typeof(myControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
             null, 
             FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
             (o, e) => ((MyControl)o).OnMYCustomDpPropChanged())); 

private void OnMYCustomDpPropChanged()
{
  //do you logic here
}
```

..then somewhere in XAML you can bind it:

```
<MyControl MYCustomDpProp={Binding MyModel.SomeProperty}"
```